# Keep all system logs, forever

Tags: macos, logs

In console app I can see only couple `system.log.${i}.gz` archived log files that can only show me info about last 10-15 days.
How to keep **all** logs archived somewhere, forever ?

Comment: Use a dedicated syslog server and send the logs there. Alternatively, change the log rotation to never delete anything.

Comment: You could give me a terminal command / article that explains just that: `Alternatively, change the log rotation to never delete anything.` ?

Comment: Here's how you can configure syslog to send data to a dedicated syslog server: https://wiki.splunk.com/Community:HowTo_Configure_Mac_OS_X_Syslog_To_Forward_Data

And if you want to play with log rotation, apparently (according to a quick DuckDuckGo search), you wanna look at /etc/asl.conf and man asl.conf.  I'm not familiar with asl, so I don't know how it works, but looking at the file and man page I imagine it can be figured out pretty quick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The log files are rotated and eventually removed by the asl system. You can change the configuration by editing /etc/asl.conf under sudo. Start Terminal.app and issue this command:

```
sudo -e /etc/asl.conf
```

You'll find in there a comment stating that rules for /var/log/system.log follows, the first line looks like this:

```
> system.log mode=0640 format=bsd rotate=seq compress file_max=5M all_max=50M
```

Change that to look like this:

```
> system.log mode=0640 format=bsd rotate=seq compress file_max=5M all_max=9999G ttl=99999
```

This means that each seperate log file will be maximum 5M. Normally the asl system removes log files when either they exceed the all_max limit (before 50 megabyte, now 9999 gigabytes) or when the file is older than ttl days (before 7 days, now 99999 days).

Comment: Do not use `sudo` to run an editor just to edit a file that requires elevated privileges to write. For security and safety reasons you should restrict the amount of code that you run as root. Instead, use `sudo -e …`, which will copy the file to `/tmp` and start your editor. When you exit the editor `sudo` then copies the file back. See the man page <x-man-page://8/sudo> for details.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that letting the system.log grow to very large size will have a performance impact on your Mac.  Large files take longer to write to than small ones.

Comment: @benwiggy Not really, no? - Appending to a very large file is no slower than appending to a smaller file. In any case, it is not relevant here as the files are no larger than before after making this change.