# Can system logs tell me when I closed my Macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, logs

I'm trying to figure out how late I've been working for the last few months.

Normally my old line manager would not have given me time in lieu. However she was fired last week and I now stand a chance of getting some time back from the company.

The best measurement of when I stop work is when I last close my macbook each day. Could I find this out from the sys logs?

Comment: Instead of just closing the Macbook and putting it to sleep, shut it down. There are log entries for system shutdown and startup.

Comment: I believe that Ward here wants to know a passed action, and not a way to do it in the future...

Comment: Shutdowns register a distinct message in system.log: `May 17 15:28:17 [redacted] com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system): System shutdown initiated by: shutdown.7478<-sessionlogoutd.7336<-launchd.1`. I can find no such distinct message for sleep.

Comment: How about looking for the last save event - surely that's about the last thing you might do or close to?

Comment: MacOS logs a prodigious amount of data. The good news is that you'll likely be able to find the log entries you need. The bad news is they may not be easy to find. I don't use the logs frequently, but as I understand it, the `console` app (in `Launchpad`, `Other`) is a tool that may prove useful. And as usual, the Internet has some tutorials: [1](https://www.howtogeek.com/406592/how-to-use-the-console-on-macos-to-check-log-and-activities/), [2](https://techbland.com/how-to-use-console-macos/). [Another take here](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/logs-logging-logger-oh/)

Comment: I don't now if this counts as update but my new line manager said to let him know what "feels right" with regards to the extra hours that I have worked. 

Comment: That makes it easy :)   Nevertheless, it's a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the closest answer I could get was this console command:

```
log show -v | grep "Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep'"
```

It's not perfect as it only goes back 6 weeks or so, and it shows more sleep messages than I need. But from the results set, its easy to pick out the last 'System Sleep' of the day.

Answer (score 1):

The last message before I opened my MacBook this morning was

```
5/19/19 22:43:36.000 kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Sleep
```

I'm not sure I closed it at that time exactly last night but it was close.

I've just run an experiment now and it took about 15 seconds from my last activity before I close the lid until that message appears.

Comment: Just an FYI... If one's Wi-Fi is turned off, that message will not be in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick bit of research, this ***may be worth a try***. Open a terminal window to get the `bash` prompt, then:

```bsh
$ sudo log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Clamshell change detected"' --last 24h
```

I've included the `--last 24h` option so that you won't be inundated with data. Use this first to confirm that this will give you the data you need. If you may want to experiment with different `predicate` options, etc you can read all about it at `man log`.

I don't know how far back the system logs go on your system, so this will avoid a huge dump to your terminal. But of course if you don't mind a huge dump to your terminal, simply remove that option from the command line. [Based on a previous answer here at "AskDifferent"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/317293/149366) the period of time that your logs will cover is apparently a function of some settings in the `/etc/asl.conf` file. That answer has a method to check & adjust those settings. However, in looking at my own `asl.conf` file, it differs some from the settings in the referenced answer (e.g. there is no `ttl` limit in my `asl.conf`). And so, you may not know how far back you can go until you actually try. If the entire period of interest isn't in the logs, I don't have any ideas, except to increase the log limits in `asl.conf` to avoid that issue in the future, or perhaps set up [log rotation](https://serverfault.com/questions/352942/equivalent-of-logrotate-on-osx).

A couple of other points:

1. If you don't use `sudo`, you may get the following odd error message:

> log: Could not open local log store: The log archive format is corrupt and cannot be read

That message is likely false and misleading; use `sudo`, and it should disappear (unless your logs truly are corrupted!).

2. If you want to save the `log` output to a file, that's easy enough:

```bsh
$ sudo log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Clamshell change detected"' --last 24h >> ~/MyClamshellClosures.txt
```

3. And finally, if you want to see log entries for a range of dates, e.g. YTD:

```bsh
$ sudo log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Clamshell change detected"' --start "2019-01-01" --end "2019-05-19" >> ~/MyClamshellClosures.txt
```

### ALTERNATIVELY:

If you don't wish to use the command line, the `Console` app in `Launchpad`, `Other` may also be used. I prefer the command line, but there are some decent and current tutorials that may help:

1. [Fm 'techbland.com', May 15, 2019](https://techbland.com/how-to-use-console-macos/)
2. [Fm 'howtogeek.com', Mar 19, 2019](https://www.howtogeek.com/406592/how-to-use-the-console-on-macos-to-check-log-and-activities/)

Comment: The OP stated "I'm trying to figure out how late I've been working for the last few months.", and the `sudo log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Clamshell change detected"'` _command_ (without the `--last 24h` _option_) only went back two weeks. So while helpful for the last two weeks, it doesn't appear to be helpful beyond that range. Also, searching in **Console** for "Clamshell change detected" only yielded  that `sudo` executed that command, so it looks like the `log` _command_ from **Terminal** will need to be used.

Comment: BTW Adding the e.g. the `--last 30d` _option_ to the `log` _command_, in an attempt to get more than two weeks, yielded the same results as without it. So it appears anything beyond two weeks will not be able to be validated in this manner and isn't sufficient to cover the time range mentioned in the OP.

Comment: @user3439894: Have you found something in the documentation stating that all logs are purged after 30 days? Could that be peculiar to your machine?

Comment: My system has been running with the default installed settings for any logging for the last year since I clean build macOS High Sierra on it. I have never run any app or issued any command that cleans up any logs. I open and close the Clamshell every day and for me it only shows the last two weeks.

Comment: @user3439894: Could you please [read this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/317293/149366), and then reconsider your comment?

Comment: I am fully aware of the contents of the link you provided in your last comment, but modifying the `/etc/asl.conf` as shown in the link of your comment is for the `/var/log/system.log` file and the "Clamshell change detected" message is not stored in the `/var/log/system.log` file on my system. So I'm not sure what relevance that part of your answer has in this scenario?

Comment: @user3439894: Perhaps you should post a question if you're not sure?

Comment: The last sentence of that comment I made was edited out by, I'm assuming, bmike because it was rhetorical and the last thing I said was "None that I can see!", so I do not need to ask a question!

Comment: @user3439894: OK, I'm so happy for you. Now you have time that you can spend on something else.